# Programmatically delete a Wagtail ListBlock item

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals, wagtail

I have an abstract class that defines a `StreamField` for a Wagtail `Page`:

```
class DownloadGroupItem(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    downloads = StreamField([
        ('items', ListBlock(
            StructBlock(
                [
                    ('title', CharBlock()),
                    ('description', TextBlock()),
                    ('file', DocumentChooserBlock()),
                ],
                template='downloads/blocks/item.html',
                form_classname='downloads__itemlist struct-block'
            ),
            label='Add download'
        ))
    ])
```

If the `file` saved via the `DocumentChooserBlock` is deleted externally from the page, this makes the `ListBlock` item invalid to output in a template. If this occurs, the current behaviour is to leave the `StructBlock` with an empty - though required - value for `file`.

I can mitigate this by adding a receiver for the Wagtail document model, and listening for `models.signals.post_delete`, but how can I programmatically delete the Wagtail ListBlock items that are affected?